# Designing logic for 7-segment display

Tags: 7segmentdisplay, decoder

I want to design the logic of a 7-segment display driver. As for the specs, I want it to have 4 inputs coding the binary value of numers 0-9 and 8 outputs for the display. I am not really sure where to start, so how would an outline of the design process look like?

Comment: Search in google with BCD to seven segment display

Comment: Your question is frankly not clear. The 4 inputs are coded how? Do you want to *use* an IC or do you want to *design* a whole discrete (or possibly integrated) circuit. Etc. Also there numerous tutorials and info pages on the web on this [like at least half-dozen youtube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=seven+segment+display+tutorial) as are more specific questions here, see the tag I've just added.

Comment: We can help with specific details, but we're not here to design the whole project for you.

Comment: Why the downvotes? They only want an outline of the process, not a whole design.

Comment: @HoustonFortney correct. All I asked for was just an outline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Write a [truth table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).
- Make a [Karnaugh Map](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) for each output and reduce.
- Implement the resulting logic.

Comment: Re: "Make a Karnaugh Map for each output and reduce." I suspect the result won't be great because optimizing multi-output functions is not the same thing as optimizing the function for each output (especially on just two-levels). You can and ideally should have multi-level sharing of sub-circuits. But for a newbie project what you suggest is alright.

Comment: That is correct. I had my newbie filter on. Really you should use an FPGA and let your logic synthesizer worry about all that.

Comment: @C.T.: Since based on your accept it seems this is what you want, [here's a lecture](http://www.cs.umb.edu/~bobw/CS341/Lecture21.pdf) where at least some of this work is done already.

Comment: And [here](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse370/09sp/lectures/10-ROM-Multilevel.pdf) is a lecture on more advanced designs; they cut down from 15 SOPs (result of individual optimizations) down to 9, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you'd decide which segments you'd like to light up with the different patterns of signals occurring on the inputs, and then figure out the logic between the inputs and outputs to make what you want to have happen, happen.

Take a look at [this data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn5447a.pdf) for a clue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [binary decoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decoder) to decode you binary input to a decimal and then use a diode matrix to "map" the digits to the right segments of your display.

Just have a look on this circuit: https://simulator.io/board/zyHHCqsJZj/1